# Proper method of block ads/tracking on VPN Server for Clients

Tags: linux, dnsmasq, hosts-file

I´m running a VPN service on Debian(for a few friends) as kind of like a self learning project to gather more experience running a secure and highly available service.

At the moment OpenVPN pushes opendns servers to the clients and clients route all traffic through my server. I would like to implement some kind of Tracking-Block, like a list of know domains/IPs that are used by ad or tracking services (yes I know the list apporach is far from good) that automatically gets blocked for the user when running the VPN. So if user A would for example visit a website shadycompany.com/wedotrackingforaliving that loads various js which connects to one of the domains in my list, the traffic will not be forwared or just dropped.

Thinking about this left me with 2 valid options:

- Use **dnsmasq** aliases on all domains to reroute all dns querys that
  contain a domain from the list to localhost
- Simply reroute to localhost via the **hosts file**

So my question is, **are there any limitations to either method?** Like max. number of rules, performance (https://serverfault.com/a/759896 - considering stated delay for hosts file lookups as `(O(log2(n))`, considering the list contains around 50000 entries atm) or security wise (bypassing dns etc.?). 
**Is there any best practice for such blocking** that is better than the dnsmasq and host file approach?

Comment: The hosts file would only affect lookups made by the local machine. The dnsmasq way would work though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [dnsmasq man page](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html), it looks like that'll definitely work.

As stated in the man page,

> It is possible to use dnsmasq to block Web advertising by using a list
>   of known banner-ad servers, all resolving to 127.0.0.1 or 0.0.0.0, in
>   /etc/hosts or an additional hosts file. The list can be very long,
>   dnsmasq has been tested successfully with one million names. That size
>   file needs a 1GHz processor and about 60Mb of RAM.

Which looks like exactly what you're trying to do.